# How should I optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am selecting a list of products from database and showing it to the user. I have already created index for the columns used in where clause then too it takes a lot of time to return and load the results.

```
SELECT 
    prod_disp.pdid, prod_disp.cat_id, prod_disp.title, prod_disp.image_url, 
    prod_disp.price, prod_stat.eyeing_ids, prod_stat.eyeing_num, 
    prod_stat.listing_num, prod_stat.reviews_num, prod_stat.reviews_score
FROM 
    products.prod_disp 
    INNER JOIN products.prod_stat ON prod_disp.pdid = prod_stat.pdid
WHERE 
    prod_disp.active='1' AND prod_disp.cat_id='7' 
ORDER BY 
    RAND()
LIMIT 0, 21;
```

Comment: Have you run an EXPLAIN on this query?

Comment: The `explain select...` sentence will help you see the execution plan of your query. Please read the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

Count the results.

Remove the order by rand().

generate a random number between 0 and Count-21, lets call it _rand

replace LIMIT 0, 21; to LIMIT _rand, _rand+21;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that ORDER BY rand() causes MySQL to internally put all the data into a temptable (which could even be written on disk) and then re-order it randomly. If it is acceptable for you, you could replace it with a random where, based on an indexed field.

You also need these index:

- prod_disp(pdid, prod_disp.cat_id, active)
- FK: products(prod_stat)